# ObjectDataSource using service class with Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I have a service layer that exposes a few methods, which are used within my **ObjectDataSource** on my asp.net application.

The constructor of the service class has a parameter, which is just an int, used to track the current logged in user:

```
public ProjectService(int userId)
{
    _userId = userId;
    pb = new ProjectBusiness(_userId);
}
```

However, my service was working fine without the parameter. Since I added it, I get hit with:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Is there a way to pass this parameter from the objectdatasource, to my service layer? Or maybe there's a better way to handle my service (and then business and data layers) knowing the UserID, which is currently stored in the Session[]?

A work around I have found, is to declare the parameter in code:

```
protected void ChargeRatesODS_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    var service = new ResourceService(Common.CurrentUserId());
    e.ObjectInstance = service;

}
```

Is this is the only way, and the best practice, then I can stick with it, but .. is this the way to handle parameters? I want the constructor to have a parameter, so that it forces the developer to pass in a valid UserID, mainly for logging and role management reasons.

Comment: You've the answer. Suggest you add your solution as an answer to this question, and mark it likewise.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my solution here as it showed up in my search initially. 
Our project used Generic service classes taking different types based on the data requested, and have a signature similar to this,

```
public class ReportDataService<T, U>
```

and the constructor had a session Id so we could keep some totals per each session, as below.

```
 public ReportDataService(string sessionGuid)
```

so the only way it worked in the page was using the type activator, so it satisfied both different generic types and different constructor parameters at the same time (code below is in .aspx.cs).

```
  void DataSource_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {

        var myType = ((ObjectDataSourceView)sender).TypeName;
        var newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(  Type.GetType( myType, false), new object[] { sessionId });
        e.ObjectInstance = newObj;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@civilator Thanks for your reply, I think it helped me too. Here is my version, translated to VB. Used this so that I can pass a parameter into the constructor of the object that is being created.

```
Protected Sub StaffDataSource_OnObjectCreating(sender As Object, e As ObjectDataSourceEventArgs)
    Dim newObj = New StaffService(Master.clsCU.UserId)
    e.ObjectInstance = newObj
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to this question. It is a copy of another's answer, but written in a different language while the OP asks for a C# solution. People with a same or similar question can be confused by your answer. Please read the [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide if you want to contribute on this site.

Comment: I am working on a project, in VB his C# code helped me, but I had to translate it to VB. Sometimes C# results show up for VB queries, sometimes VB shows up for C#. I am just trying to help people who found this thread, but don't specifically need the C#.